# No puedo modificar los objetos de un formulario

Tags: python, tablas

con la siguiente instrucción pretendo rellenar cajas de texto cuando de clic en un registro de una tabla previamente cargada

`self.tblDocente.cellClicked.connect(self.SelecReg) #cuando doy clic en una fila me muestra los resultados`

la función o método la creo así

```
    def SelecReg(self):#selecciona con un clic y muestra en pantalla lo seleccionado             
        print("12345")
        print("esto es una prueba de selccion de registro")        
        ced=self.tblDocente.selectedIndexes()[0].data()        
        nom=self.tblDocente.selectedIndexes()[1].data()
        ape=self.tblDocente.selectedIndexes()[2].data()
        forma=self.tblDocente.selectedIndexes()[3].data()
        dir=self.tblDocente.selectedIndexes()[4].data()
        tel=self.tblDocente.selectedIndexes()[5].data()
        email=self.tblDocente.selectedIndexes()[6].data()    
        self.txtCed.setText(ced)
        self.txtNom.setText(nom)
        self.txtApe.setText(ape)
        self.txtDir.setText(dir)
        self.txtTel.setText(tel)
        self.txtFormacion.setText(forma)
        self.txtMail.setText(email)
        self.__init__(2)
```

el problema es que únicamente me ejecuta las dos primeras instrucciones print, el resto no las hace , solo las ignora como si no estuviesen , al compilarlo no genera error, cabe anotar que este procedimiento lo implemente como una función y trabajó perfectamente, al pasarlo a un método de una clase empezó a generarme estos problemas.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: yo cargo una tabla con atributos, y quiero que cuando posicione el cursor y de clic sobre algunos de los registros de la tabla pues estos mismo valores me aparezcan en las cajitas de texto.

Comment: "Hacer clic" sugiere que estás usando alguna biblioteca para interfaces gráficas (Qt, tkinter, otra?) o quizás es un servidor web y la tabla está en html (flask, django, fastapi, otra?) ¿Cuál es ese framework? Probablemente sea necesario además ver más código, como desde dónde llamas a la función.

Comment: si tienes toda la razon, estoy usando PyQt5 y visual studio code como IDE, ya te compartiré el código completo